# Не корректно работает отдельно созданная страница в WordPress

Tags: wordpress, шаблоны, плагин

Здравствуйте!

Создал отдельную свою страницу в шаблоне Wordpress http://free-pc.ru/podpiska-2.

На страницу вставил подписную форму от плагина "WP Subscribe Pro".

Но данная форма не хочет работать, так как я думаю на данную страницу из WordPress не передаются данные плагина.

Попробовал вставить на страницу вызов header.php на страницу до моего кода и вызов footer.php после. Все работает. Но при этом появляются лишние элементы на странице (шапка, меню и т.д.)...

Какое решение предложите Вы?
Может быть вставить минимальный код из header.php и footer.php, лишь бы работал плагин? Тогда покажите мне какие именно строки кода мне вставить.

Код header.php и footer.php прилагаю...

**header.php...**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>

<!-- Скрипт от VK.com (Комментарии) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?116"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  VK.init({apiId: 4367436, onlyWidgets: true});
</script>

</head>
<?php global $is_IE ?>
<body id="top" <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div class="wrapper-outer">

<?php if( tie_get_option('banner_bg_url') && tie_get_option('banner_bg') ): ?>
 <a href="<?php echo esc_url( tie_get_option('banner_bg_url') ) ?>" target="_blank" class="background-cover"></a>
<?php else: ?>
 <div class="background-cover"></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(  tie_get_option( 'mobile_menu_active' ) ): ?>
 <aside id="slide-out">
 
 <?php if( tie_get_option( 'mobile_menu_search' ) ): ?>
  <div class="search-mobile">
   <form method="get" id="searchform-mobile" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">
    <button class="search-button" type="submit" value="<?php if( !$is_IE ) _eti( 'Search' ) ?>"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> 
    <input type="text" id="s-mobile" name="s" title="<?php _eti( 'Search' ) ?>" value="<?php _eti( 'Search' ) ?>" onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php _eti( 'Search' ) ?>') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php _eti( 'Search' ) ?>';}"  />
   </form>
  </div><!-- .search-mobile /-->
 <?php endif; ?>
 
 <?php if( tie_get_option('mobile_menu_social') ):
  tie_get_social( true , false , 'ttip-none' ); ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
 
  <div id="mobile-menu" <?php if( !tie_get_option('mobile_menu_hide_icons') ) echo' class="mobile-hide-icons"';?>></div>
 </aside><!-- #slide-out /-->
<?php endif; ?>

 <?php $full_width  =''; if( tie_get_option( 'full_logo' ))  $full_width  = ' full-logo';
    $center_logo =''; if( tie_get_option( 'center_logo' ))  $center_logo = ' center-logo';
    $theme_layout = 'boxed';

    if( tie_get_option( 'theme_layout' ) == 'full' )   $theme_layout = 'wide-layout';
    if( tie_get_option( 'theme_layout' ) == 'boxed-all' ) $theme_layout = 'boxed-all';
 ?>
 <div id="wrapper" class="<?php echo $theme_layout ?>">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">

  <header id="theme-header" class="theme-header<?php echo $full_width.$center_logo ?>">
   <?php if( tie_get_option( 'top_menu' ) ): ?>
   <div id="top-nav" class="top-nav">
    <div class="container">

   <?php if(tie_get_option( 'top_date' )):
    if( tie_get_option('todaydate_format') ) $date_format = tie_get_option('todaydate_format');
    else $date_format = 'l ,  j  F Y';
   ?>
    <span class="today-date"><?php  echo date_i18n( $date_format , current_time( 'timestamp' ) ); ?></span><?php endif; ?>
     
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'top-menu', 'theme_location' => 'top-menu'  ) ); ?>

 <?php if( tie_get_option( 'top_search' ) ): ?>
     <div class="search-block">
      <form method="get" id="searchform-header" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">
       <button class="search-button" type="submit" value="<?php if( !$is_IE ) _eti( 'Search' ) ?>"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> 
       <input class="search-live" type="text" id="s-header" name="s" title="<?php _eti( 'Search' ) ?>" value="<?php _eti( 'Search' ) ?>" onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php _eti( 'Search' ) ?>') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php _eti( 'Search' ) ?>';}"  />
      </form>
     </div><!-- .search-block /-->
 <?php endif;
 if( tie_get_option('top_social') ):
  tie_get_social( true , false , 'ttip-none' ); ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
 
 <?php tie_language_selector_flags(); ?>

    </div><!-- .container /-->
   </div><!-- .top-menu /-->
   <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="header-content">
  
  <?php if(  tie_get_option( 'mobile_menu_active' ) ): ?>
   <a id="slide-out-open" class="slide-out-open" href="#"><span></span></a>
  <?php endif; ?>
  
<?php
if( is_category() || is_single() ){
 if( is_category() ) $category_id = get_query_var('cat') ;
 if( is_single() ){ 
  $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );
  if( !empty( $categories[0]->term_id ) )
   $category_id = $categories[0]->term_id ;
 }
 
 if( !empty( $category_id ) ){
  $tie_cats_options = get_option( 'tie_cats_options' );
  if( !empty( $tie_cats_options[ $category_id ] ) )
   $cat_options = $tie_cats_options[ $category_id ];
 }
}

if( !empty($cat_options['cat_custom_logo']) ){

 $logo_margin ='';
 if( !empty( $cat_options['logo_margin'] ) || !empty( $cat_options['logo_margin_bottom'] ) ){
  $logo_margin = ' style="';
  if( !empty( $cat_options['logo_margin'] ) )
   $logo_margin .= ' margin-top:'.$cat_options['logo_margin'].'px;';
  if( !empty( $cat_options['logo_margin_bottom'] ) )
   $logo_margin .= ' margin-bottom:'.$cat_options['logo_margin_bottom'].'px;';
  $logo_margin .= '"';
 }
 ?>
   <div class="logo"<?php echo $logo_margin ?>>
   <h2>
<?php if( $cat_options['logo_setting'] == 'title' ): ?>
    <a  href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/"><?php echo single_cat_title( '', false ) ?></a>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php if( !empty($cat_options['logo']) ) $logo = $cat_options['logo'];
    elseif( tie_get_option( 'logo' ) ) $logo = tie_get_option( 'logo' );
      else $logo = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/logo.png';
    ?>
    <a title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">
     <img src="<?php echo $logo ; ?>" alt="<?php echo single_cat_title( '', false ) ?>" <?php if(  $cat_options['logo_retina_width'] && $cat_options['logo_retina_height'] ) echo 'width="'.$cat_options['logo_retina_width'] .'" height="'.$cat_options['logo_retina_height'].'"'; ?> /><strong><?php echo single_cat_title( '', false ) ?></strong>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
   </h2>
   </div><!-- .logo /-->
<?php if( $cat_options['logo_retina'] && $cat_options['logo_retina_width'] && $cat_options['logo_retina_height']): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var retina = window.devicePixelRatio > 1 ? true : false;
 if(retina) {
        jQuery('#theme-header .logo img').attr('src',  '<?php echo $cat_options['logo_retina']; ?>');
        jQuery('#theme-header .logo img').attr('width',  '<?php echo $cat_options['logo_retina_width']; ?>');
        jQuery('#theme-header .logo img').attr('height', '<?php echo $cat_options['logo_retina_height']; ?>');
 }
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
}else{
 $logo_margin ='';
 if( tie_get_option( 'logo_margin' ) || tie_get_option( 'logo_margin_bottom' ) ){
  $logo_margin = ' style="';
  if( tie_get_option( 'logo_margin' ) )
   $logo_margin .= ' margin-top:'.tie_get_option( 'logo_margin' ).'px;';
  if( tie_get_option( 'logo_margin_bottom' ) )
   $logo_margin .= ' margin-bottom:'.tie_get_option( 'logo_margin_bottom' ).'px;';
  $logo_margin .= '"';
 }
?>
   <div class="logo"<?php echo $logo_margin ?>>
   <?php if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) echo '<h1>'; else echo '<h2>'; ?>
<?php if( tie_get_option('logo_setting') == 'title' ): ?>
    <a  href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
    <span><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></span>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php if( tie_get_option( 'logo' ) ) $logo = tie_get_option( 'logo' );
      else $logo = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/logo.png';
    ?>
    <a title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">
     <img src="<?php echo $logo ; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" <?php if(  tie_get_option('logo_retina_width') && tie_get_option('logo_retina_height') ) echo 'width="'.tie_get_option('logo_retina_width') .'" height="'.tie_get_option('logo_retina_height').'"'; ?> /><strong><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></strong>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
   <?php if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) echo '</h1>'; else echo '</h2>'; ?>
   </div><!-- .logo /-->
<?php if( tie_get_option( 'logo_retina' ) && tie_get_option( 'logo_retina_width' ) && tie_get_option( 'logo_retina_height' )): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var retina = window.devicePixelRatio > 1 ? true : false;
 if(retina) {
        jQuery('#theme-header .logo img').attr('src',  '<?php echo tie_get_option( 'logo_retina' ); ?>');
        jQuery('#theme-header .logo img').attr('width',  '<?php echo tie_get_option( 'logo_retina_width' ); ?>');
        jQuery('#theme-header .logo img').attr('height', '<?php echo tie_get_option( 'logo_retina_height' ); ?>');
 }
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
   <?php tie_banner('banner_top' , '<div class="e3lan e3lan-top">' , '</div>' ); ?>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   
  </div> 
  <?php $stick = ''; ?>
  <?php if( tie_get_option( 'stick_nav' ) ) $stick = ' class="fixed-enabled"' ?>
   <?php if( tie_get_option( 'main_nav' ) ): ?>
   <?php
   //UberMenu Support
   $navID = 'main-nav';
   if ( class_exists( 'UberMenu' ) ){
    $uberMenus = get_option( 'wp-mega-menu-nav-locations' );
    if( !empty($uberMenus) && is_array($uberMenus) && in_array("primary", $uberMenus)) $navID = 'main-nav-uber';
   }?>
   <nav id="<?php echo $navID; ?>"<?php echo $stick; ?>>
    <div class="container">
    
    <?php if( tie_get_option( 'nav_logo' ) ): ?>
     <a class="main-nav-logo" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">
      <img src="<?php echo tie_get_option( 'nav_logo' ) ?>" width="195" height="54" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
     </a>
    <?php endif ?>

     <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'main-menu', 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'walker' => new tie_mega_menu_walker(), 'fallback_cb'=> false) ); ?>
     <?php if(tie_get_option( 'random_article' )): ?>
     <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?tierand=1" class="random-article ttip" title="<?php _eti( 'Random Article' ) ?>"><i class="fa fa-random"></i></a>
     <?php endif ?>

     <?php if( tie_get_option( 'shopping_cart' ) && function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) ):
      global $woocommerce; ?>
      <a class="tie-cart ttip" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _eti( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>"><span class="shooping-count-outer"><?php if( isset( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count ) && ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count != 0 ) ){ ?><span class="shooping-count"><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count ?></span><?php } ?><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></span></a>
     <?php endif ?>

    </div>
   </nav><!-- .main-nav /-->
   <?php endif; ?>
  </header><!-- #header /-->
 
 <?php get_template_part( 'framework/parts/breaking-news' ); // Get Breaking News template ?> 
 
 <?php tie_banner('banner_below_header' , '<div class="e3lan e3lan-below_header">' , '</div>' ); ?>

<?php 
$sidebar = '';
if( tie_get_option( 'sidebar_pos' ) == 'left' ) $sidebar = ' sidebar-left';
if( is_singular() || ( function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) && is_woocommerce() ) ){

 $current_ID = $post->ID;
 if( function_exists( 'is_woocommerce' ) && is_woocommerce() ) $current_ID = woocommerce_get_page_id('shop');

 $get_meta = get_post_custom( $current_ID );
 if( !empty($get_meta["tie_sidebar_pos"][0]) ){
  $sidebar_pos = $get_meta["tie_sidebar_pos"][0];

  if( $sidebar_pos == 'left' ) $sidebar = ' sidebar-left';
  elseif( $sidebar_pos == 'full' ) $sidebar = ' full-width';
  elseif( $sidebar_pos == 'right' ) $sidebar = ' sidebar-right';
 }
}
if(  function_exists('is_bbpress') && is_bbpress() && tie_get_option( 'bbpress_full' )) $sidebar = ' full-width';
?>
 <div id="main-content" class="container<?php echo $sidebar ; ?>">
```

**footer.php...**

```html
<div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- .container /-->
<?php tie_banner('banner_bottom' , '<div class="e3lan e3lan-bottom">' , '</div>' ); ?>

<?php get_sidebar( 'footer' ); ?>    
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="footer-bottom">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="alignright">
   <?php
    $footer_vars = array('%year%' , '%site%' , '%url%');
    $footer_val  = array( date('Y') , get_bloginfo('name') , home_url() );
    $footer_two  = str_replace( $footer_vars , $footer_val , tie_get_option( 'footer_two' ));
    echo htmlspecialchars_decode( $footer_two );?>
  </div>
  <?php if( tie_get_option('footer_social') ) tie_get_social( true , false, 'ttip-none' ); ?>
  
  <div class="alignleft">
   <?php
    $footer_one  = str_replace( $footer_vars , $footer_val , tie_get_option( 'footer_one' ));
    echo htmlspecialchars_decode( $footer_one );?>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </div><!-- .Container -->
</div><!-- .Footer bottom -->

</div><!-- .inner-Wrapper -->
</div><!-- #Wrapper -->
</div><!-- .Wrapper-outer -->
<?php if( tie_get_option('footer_top') ): ?>
 <div id="topcontrol" class="fa fa-angle-up" title="<?php _eti( 'Scroll To Top' ); ?>"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<?php wp_footer();?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какой именно код нужно оставить вам в footer.php и header.php зависит от того какие элементы вам нужно сохранить. Но основное почему без них не работает форма мне видится это вот эти две функции wp_head();  wp_footer();
Оставте по минимуму

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>

<!-- Скрипт от VK.com (Комментарии) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?116"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  VK.init({apiId: 4367436, onlyWidgets: true});
</script>

</head>
```

**footer.php**

```
<?php wp_footer();?>
</body>
</html>
```

Если форма работает то добавляйте остальные элементы, которые вам нужны. А вообще для форм есть более интересное как по мне решение https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/